# Perform Calculations from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables on a database with the same set up.

[image]

I want to be able to perform sums off them so i can identify the difference between them.
e.g. Category career = total points difference = 294 and 69.7% increase
I have been able to complete this exercise on a table where there is only 1 row but now its saying 
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

This is the code I was trying to use, i'd want it to compare for each of the different categories and there are more rows and columns in the table that I'm not showing.

```
    SELECT   Category,
(SELECT TotalPoints FROM xMetrics02Category) - (SELECT TotalPoints FROM xMetrics06CategoryHIST) AS pointsDiff
FROM xMetrics02Category
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So basically you could `JOIN` over carreer, no? And then you could perform a simple calculation between the two columns...!? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What are you expecting as output here? Of course you can't use a subquery like you are trying here. Most likely a join would fix this. But we need more details. See this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the total structure of your Tables, this query might solve the problem at hand:

```
SELECT c.Category
      ,c.TotalPoints - ch.TotalPoints AS PointsDiff
  FROM xMetrics02Category c
  JOIN xMetrics06CategoryHIST ch ON ch.Category = c.Category
```

Comment: Oh wow, that worked. I and i can continue doing other sums as required. So simple really - why couldn't i work that out